# How to use SQLExceptionTranslator and Oracle UCP together

Tags: java, spring, oracle, ucp

I use Oracle UCP as connection pool driver.
I try to use [SQLExceptionTranslator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/class-use/SQLExceptionTranslator.html) in my JdbcTemplate but there is a problem.
When I implement my own SqlExceptionTranslator implementation with overrided customTranslate() and if there is an Exception on db side I have the following:

```java
...java.sql.SQLException: Exception occurred while getting connection: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: Universal Connection Pool internal error: **java.lang.ClassCastException: class oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException cannot be cast to class java.sql.SQLException** (oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @6f496d9f; java.sql.SQLException is in module java.sql of loader 'platform')
            at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.newSQLException(UCPErrorHandler.java:498) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.throwSQLException(UCPErrorHandler.java:175) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:1899) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.access$300(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:224) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl$3.build(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:4050) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:1822) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:1778) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:1764) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:159) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.4.jar!/:6.0.4]
            at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:117) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.4.jar!/:6.0.4]
            at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.4.jar!/:6.0.4]
            ... 33 more
    Caused by: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: Universal Connection Pool internal error: java.lang.ClassCastException: class oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException cannot be cast to class java.sql.SQLException (oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @6f496d9f; java.sql.SQLException is in module java.sql of loader 'platform')
            at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.newUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:378) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.throwUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:68) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.throwUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:91) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.throwUniversalConnectionPoolException(UCPErrorHandler.java:164) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.common.Core.growBorrowed(Core.java:1289) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.helpGrowBorrowed(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:406) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.borrowConnectionWithoutCountingRequests(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:349) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.borrowConnectionAndValidateHelper(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:205) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.borrowConnectionAndValidate(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:165) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.borrowConnection(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:138) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.jdbc.JDBCConnectionPool.borrowConnection(JDBCConnectionPool.java:184) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.jdbc.oracle.OracleJDBCConnectionPool.borrowConnection(OracleJDBCConnectionPool.java:610) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.jdbc.oracle.OracleConnectionConnectionPool.borrowConnection(OracleConnectionConnectionPool.java:118) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:1879) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.access$300(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:224) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl$3.build(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:4050) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:1822) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:1778) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:1764) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:159) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.4.jar!/:6.0.4]
            at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:117) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.4.jar!/:6.0.4]
            at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.4.jar!/:6.0.4]
            ... 33 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException cannot be cast to class java.sql.SQLException (oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @6f496d9f; java.sql.SQLException is in module java.sql of loader 'platform')
            at oracle.ucp.common.Service.create(Service.java:897) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.common.Service.create(Service.java:644) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.common.Topology.create(Topology.java:163) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.common.Core.growBorrowed(Core.java:1279) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.helpGrowBorrowed(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:406) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.borrowConnectionWithoutCountingRequests(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:349) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.borrowConnectionAndValidateHelper(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:205) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.borrowConnectionAndValidate(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:165) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.common.UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.borrowConnection(UniversalConnectionPoolImpl.java:138) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.jdbc.JDBCConnectionPool.borrowConnection(JDBCConnectionPool.java:184) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.jdbc.oracle.OracleJDBCConnectionPool.borrowConnection(OracleJDBCConnectionPool.java:610) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.jdbc.oracle.OracleConnectionConnectionPool.borrowConnection(OracleConnectionConnectionPool.java:118) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:1879) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.access$300(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:224) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl$3.build(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:4050) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:1822) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:1778) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.getConnection(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:1764) ~[ucp-21.8.0.0.jar!/:21.8.0.0.0]
            at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:159) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.4.jar!/:6.0.4]
            at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:117) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.4.jar!/:6.0.4]
            at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.4.jar!/:6.0.4]
            ... 33 more
```

I suppose that the reason is that the oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException extends java.lang.Exception - a customTranslate overrided method requires java.sql.SQLException.

But, how to use SQLExceptionTranslator/jdbcTemplate.setExceptionTranslator feature with Oracle UCP ?

Best Regards

koli

Answer (score 0):

That was a bug fixed in the recent releases.
Which UCP release are you using? If not fixed in your release, please submit an Oracle Support service request to get a one-off patch.